# Alternative to RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently passing a parameter to a `SQL` string like this -

```
grid=0&
```

And I am using a `RegEx` to get the `0` value like so-

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"grid=([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\&$",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string grid = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

which works perfectly.

However as development has progressed it is clear that more parameters will be added to the string like so-

```
grid=0&hr=3&tb=0
```

These parameters may come in a different order in the string each time so clearly the RegEx I am currently using wont work. I have looked into it and think `Split` may be an option however not sure.

What would the best method be and how could I apply it to my current problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're parsing query string and looking for an alternative to `Regex`, there is a specialized class and method for that, it returns collection of parameters:

```
        string s = "http://www.something.com?grid=0&hr=3&tb=0";
        Uri uri = new Uri(s);
        var result = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

You have to include `System.Web` namespace.
You can access each of the parameters' values by using it's key:

```
        foreach (string key in result.Keys)
        {
            string value = result[key];
            // action...
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I have implemented it, but how could I use the value? as in pass over them to determine when to use them? As they are likely to change...

Answer (score 1):

Regexes can still be used here.  Consider adding another capture group to capture the property name, and then looping over all of the results using Matches rather that Match, or calling Match multiple times.

Comment: You are on the right path but this won't match the tb parameter in the second example as it does not have a trailing &. Also I'd use named groups to make it clearer `(?<name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)=(?<value>[A-Za-z0-9]+)`then `match.groups["name"]` and `match.groups["value"]`